# move_uploaded_file in php is not working in mobile browser When pic taken from camera, but it is working with desktop browser

Tags: php, file, codeigniter-2

Im using the below code to move a uploaded file into a location in server.

```
if( $_FILES)
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['newfile']['tmp_name'][0], "uploads".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."jersey".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$jersey_id.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."jersey_logo_".$_FILES['newfile']['name'][0]);
```

The above code works fine, when i use browser in my pc. But the same fails when using mobile browser's camera and files selected from camera folder and the same works if files are selected from other folders.

The $_FILES array is follows[image]

what will be the reason?

Comment: have you looked into `$_FILES` array?

Comment: The default PHP values are 2 MB for upload_max_filesize, and 8 MB for post_max_size. Depending on your host, changing these two PHP variables can be done in a number of places with the most likely being php.ini or .htaccess (depending on your hosting situation)... Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size

Comment: @NeerajSingh, u r legend

Comment: @arun call me Super Saiyan ;) I am Goku's friend.. Ha Ha ha...:)

Comment: @Neeraj Singh you solved my 5 hours problem. thanks, you are legend XD